# Creating elements inside an unordered list

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've got a function that creates an unordered list in a form.  I have another function that is supposed to add items to the list according to the selected value of a select box.  The second function adds items to the list and they have the appropriate id's and whatnot, but no text.  I cannot get the items to have text in them no matter what I try.  Here is the current contents of the JavaScript function.

```
function anotherItem()
{

var textValue = document.forms['newForm'].selectBox1.value;
var ul = document.getElementById("newList");    
var new_item = document.createElement("li");
new_item.id = textValue;
new_item.innerHtml = textValue; // I've also tried new_item.value = textValue among variations.
ul.insertBefore(new_item, ul.firstChild);


}
```

Comment: `innerHtml -> innerHTML`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML. Also make sure that the ID value you assign is valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
5|    new_item.innerHtml = textValue; 
 |                  └┬─┘
 |                   └───Should be "HTML"
```

[JavaScript is case-sensitive.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity) Now `textValue` should be written in the create `li`.

<s>(It should had created an error if you put `innerHtml`, if you look in the console.)</s>

***Test it out:*** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/svUqG/

Comment: No, there would not be an error. If a property does not exist yet, it's just created when you assign to it (which you probably know, but that is what is happening here).

Comment: @FelixKling - Totally forgot about that. Good catch.